# SQLSTATE[42S02]: laravel reset the password

Tags: laravel

In Lavarel, I have the following error:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S02)
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'proforce.password_resets' doesn't exist (SQL: delete from `password_resets` where `email` = myusermail@gmail.com)

I tried to reset the password when reset enter email id and post data. I still have this error. I don't have any further idea...

Comment: i try to reset the password when reset enter email id and post data getting this error i dont have any idea..

Comment: This is a clear error. You don't have `password_resets` table in your database.

Comment: Did you run migrations?

Answer (score 1):

run command (make sure you have password_resets migration file):

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the old password_resets file in another folder , then run

> php artisan make:migration create_password_resets_table

copy content of old file to new migration file in functions up and down , then run

> php artisan migrate